# Taint source vs Taint entry point

Tags: fortify

What is the difference between Taint source and Taint entry point? I saw somewhere that both are different, but heard people using them interchangeably.

Can someone explain me in detail. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Per Fortify_Glossary document (p29),Taint Source and Taint Entry Point would be the same thing:

### taint sink

```
A program point where tainted data must not flow. When the Dataflow Analyzer finds a point where data can flow from source to sink, it reports an issue.
```

### taint source

```
A program point through which tainted data enters, such as a function that reads data from an untrusted data source.
```

However, we should be aware of that taint flags can be categories into 3 categories:

### Taint Flag Source: (Taint Flag Categories)

**General (inidcates data from outside of an application)**

```
CONSTANTFILE, DATABASE, FORM, GUI_FORM, NETWORK, SERIALIZED, STREAM, WEB, WEBSERVICE
```

**Specific ( indicates data from inside of an application)**

```
ARGS, FILE_SYSTEM, ENVIRONMENT, PRIVATE, PROPERTY, REGISTRY, STDIN, SYSTEMINFO
```

**Neutral: describes the properties of the data**

```
NUMBER, EXCEPTIONINFO, VALIDATED_issue category, etc.
```